# "Attribute 'Dependency' is not valid on this declaration type." error

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container

Why I receive such message?

Attribute 'Dependency' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'assembly' declarations.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private OverviewViewModel _vm;

    [Dependency]
    public OverviewViewModel VM
    {
        set
        {
            _vm = value;
            this.DataContext = _vm;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a minor point - set-only properties are *incredibly* rare. Are you sure this is the best approach?

Comment: it's what `Jason Dolinger` do in his `mvvm video tutorial`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong attribute: [DependencyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.dependencyattribute.aspx)

> Indicates when a dependency is to be loaded by the referring assembly [...]

and can only be applied to assemblies (and not to properties like you are trying), e.g.:

```
[assembly: Dependency(/*...*/)]
```

Comment: I think so, how to force VS to use "Unity" Dependency attribute?

Answer (score 5):

Attributes are allowed to declare what they can apply to (via AttributeUsageAttribute). The default is *anything*, but in this case it is "assembly", meaning: you can only apply this at the assembly level, which you do via:

```
[assembly:Dependency(...)]
```

If this is your own attribute, check the AttributeUsageAttribute associated with it, and ensure it includes properties (using the pipe `|` to apply "or").

If it is not your attribute, double-check the intended usage - you might be using it wrong.

Comment: hmmm... probably i'm using wrong Dependency attribute. tooltip says that this is `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DependencyAttribute` but I do need Unity `Dependency` attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Try including the getter:

```
private OverviewViewModel _vm;

[Dependency]
public OverviewViewModel VM
{
    set
    {
        _vm = value;
        this.DataContext = _vm;
    }
    get
    {
        return _vm;
    }
}
```